# Is this an isolated equilibrium point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, differential-field

I've just been learning the definition of an isolated equilibrium point. From my understanding of this definition, I would expect (as an example) the point $x=1$ to be an isolated fixed point for the differential equation $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = x-1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Fixed point? Did you mean equilibrium point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

$1$ is an isolated equilibrium point as we can find a neighbourhood around it which does not contain any other equilibrium points (there's no other equilibrium points for the equation).